# Artifactory: Failed to parse mime types, version not found

Tags: centos, java, updates, jfrog

We are trying to update artifactory from 6.1 to 6.11. A harmless update, some might say, but that's not taking into account murphy's law!

We use the recommended procedure from jfrog for updating, which is updating the package: `sudo yum update jfrog-artifactory-pro`. When we restart after the update, the following messages appear in our logs:

```
Failed to parse mime types file from: /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/mimetypes.xml

...

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Version 10 no found.
```

On our last update, we had the same problem, but managed to workaround it. We changed the `version` property in `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/mimetypes.xml` from 10 to 9. Artifactory was now starting cleanly. The problem is now back, and we'd like to know what's causing it. Are we missing a dependency? What are mimetypes, and how do they link to artifactory? Can we update our mimetype version, and if so, how?

EDIT: We tried the update on our approbation server,and it went flawlessly. There shouldn't be any major differences between the two, so I'm looking into it. I do know however that both servers have the same java version on it, so I doubt this is the issue.

Specs:

Current package: jfrog-artifactory-pro-6.1.0-60100900.noarch
Target package: jfrog-artifactory-pro-6.11.1-61101900.noarch
OS: CentOS Linux 7
Java: 1.8.0_202

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 6.12.1 of Artifactory has solved this issue. Update your installation with yum and you should be good to go.

Be aware that we haven't found out what caused the issue tough.